# P2P Audio stream Linux server software

Tags: linux, audio, streaming, p2p, broadcast

I am in search of a server software which can stream different audios to  a different clients.

For example every client will be able to create his own playlist and the server will stream it

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: So... did you want peer-to-peer or client-server?

Comment: I am not sure what will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can check flash which has support for RTMP to stream audio real time using client server & RTMFP which works over peer to peer technology. You can use RTMFP in case peer is directly reachable else  use RTMP. There is a open source red5 media server which also has support for RTMP protocol.